# How can I avoid nested subscribe in rxjs?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an code with nested subscribes:

```
      .subscribe((data) => {
        const { game, prizes } = data;
        this.ticketService.setListOfTickets(game.tickets);
        this.ticketService.getListOfTickets().subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.listOfTickets = data;
        });
        this.game = game;
        this.type = game.type;
        this.combinations = prizes.map((el: Prize) => el.patterns).flat();
      });
```

How can i improve this code to avoid nested subscription?

Comment: Does the order of operations, especially of `setListOfTickets` and `getListOfTickets` matter? Also if `getListOfTickets` is an async operation, is `setListOfTickets` maybe also async?

Comment: @churill thanks for pointing that out, I don't think setListOfTickets is async but I think it setups the getListOfTickets call, I have changed my answer to reflect this.

Comment: What is the point of setListOfTickets? Are those tickets used anywhere else in the service? Maybe it would make sense to pass the list of tickets in the getListOfTickets parameter list.

Comment: One thing I would advise against doing is naming a function parameter the same as a variable that is already in scope. data is already in use when you name the nested functions parameter data. It would be best to use a more descriptive name like listOfTickets that represents what the data is rather than a generic name like data, especially when it changes scope of data in the function.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is allowed here (probably not), but coincidentally, I did a video about nested subscriptions and how to avoid them today. You can find it here: https://youtu.be/KiJ-e5QuWe4

Answer (score 1):

```
.pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
      this.ticketService.setListOfTickets(data.game.tickets);
      return this.ticketService.getListOfTickets().pipe(
        map(listOfTickets => ({ ...data, listOfTickets }))
      );
    })
)
.subscribe(({ game, prizes, listOfTickets }) => {
    this.listOfTickets = listOfTickets;
    this.game = game;
    this.type = game.type;
    this.combinations = prizes.map((el: Prize) => el.patterns).flat();
});
```

switchMap takes the result of the firstCall and uses the result to switch to an inner observable.

Comment: This changes the order of operations too, `setListOfTickets` is now called _after_ `getListOfTickets`. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: I didn't notice the setListOfTickets, this does make the second call dependent on the first so I have moved the setListOfTickets into the switchMap. You cannot use forkJoin as the first call needs to return the data first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forkJoin and join multiple calls into single subscription. From your code is not visible the name of the function that are you subscribing on, so I just used name: *gameService.getGames()*

```
forkJoin([this.gameService.getGames(),this.ticketService.getListOfTickets()]).subscribe((data) => {
        const { game, prizes } = data[0];
        this.ticketService.setListOfTickets(game.tickets);
        this.listOfTickets = data[1];
        this.game = game;
        this.type = game.type;
        this.combinations = prizes.map((el: Prize) => el.patterns).flat();
      });
```

Comment: This changes the order of operations, e.g. `setListOfTickets` is now called _after_ `getListOfTickets`. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: @churill Not sure either. I assumed that it does not matter, because it takes as input parameters game.tickets, but I can be also important, but from the summited code we can't tell exactly.